# Generate PDF file from jacoco and pit

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, maven-pdf-plugin

- My jacoco and pit coverage are in target/site.
- I'm trying to convert them to pdf. I'm using maven-pdf plugin.
- The maven-pdf plugin converted checkstyle and surefire into pdf, but not jacoco and pit.

Any suggestions?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pdf</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>pdf</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                <includeReports>true</includeReports>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default output folder value for Jacoco is `${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco`, default value for `site` folder in `maven-pdf-plugin` is `${basedir}/src/site`.

So, you need to configure `maven-pdf-plugin`, to see, where Jacoco reports contain.

```
...
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
    <includeReports>true</includeReports>
    <siteDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</siteDirectory> <!-- specify your jacoco reports folder-->
</configuration>
```

...

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting this in the console. `Skipped external "JaCoCo" report (not supported by pdf plugin)`

Comment: it seems right, because Jacoco supports xml, csv and html formats. if you want reports in pdf, try to use sonarqube. but it is another question. if it is answer your first question - mark it as the right answer please. \

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your response.